# Composite pages in Trac

Tags: trac, wiki

Is there a feature (or plugin, or macro) in Trac that allows one to include sections from other wiki pages?

For instance, if each of my servers has a wiki page about it, and a section on the DNS info, is it possible to create a page that contains only the DNS sections of all the server pages? A link to the live section of course, not a copy.

Even better, some way to label sections and then have automatic summaries of them. e.g. Label a section "troubleshooting" on a server's page and it gets included in the "troubleshooting" summary page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several options here

1. [Include Macro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/IncludeMacro). I'm using this on a site and it works great.
2. [Include Pages Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/IncludePagesPlugin), a fork of the Include Macro with more features.
3. [Wiki Include Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiIncludePlugin). This may be more what you're looking for though as it's limited to just another wiki page, as opposed to the others supporting external URLs.

Comment: Almost! But, unless I missed it, none of those solutions allow me include just a section of another page?

Comment: You could move that section to its own wiki page, then include it on the 2 pages it's needed on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trac-admin "wiki import"/"wiki export" and any language to create page with DNS info.

Comment: No, that's going to give me a snapshot. I want to include the "live" section from another page.